# Is suggesting one app multiple times with more than a half in the answers talking about my usage acceptable?

Tags: discussion, moderation, spam, deleted-answers

Yesterday I posted a bunch of answers recommending a particular software. Some of them were deleted for not being tailored to the specific questions, and I agreed with it. But they still aren't undeleted after I edited them, and [the mod suggests me to ask other mods](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41623828#41623828), and I decide to take it to meta. Note that I'm not criticize them for not being fair. Everyone has works; if tailoring for the specific questions already make me overwhelmed, then how can they be not overwhelming for catching all the bad answers?

Let's focus on [this deleted answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/47499/6389):

- **Ignore extra wishes**: it seems to be a perfectly acceptable in this site to answer the question partly, even in the core features. Example: the other answer in the link.
- **Too passionate**: it depends on the viewpoint I think. Sure, I can see I'm being passionate myself, but I also want to convey the exact reason I stick to it. As said in one deleted comment, I've spent a lot of time to try out a a lot of tracking apps, *all* miss at least one important feature. Then this app came in and clicked on every button on my head. Going through the time of hoping new suggested apps will be the right ones working for me, then disappointed for being not, I know the frustration myself. Sure, suggesting Libre Office for a simple need is overkill, but suggesting Stack Exchange for a person who's struggling with Yahoo and Quora is not either.

[image]

Comment: Let me again point out that nowhere it was said "too passionate" – and don't forget the fact the answers were very close to being exact copies of each other (especially the personal part, which made up ~4/5 of each). As for "perfectly acceptable example": if we'd flag everything not matching our aimed standard, you'd call us rude, doctrinaire, and other names :) // Disclosure: I was the mod suggesting this. And for additional context, please start the chat log [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41620882#41620882) (half a page earlier).

Comment: But isn't what you said close to that word? The personal part is copied, but since it doesn't really answer the questions, so I guess being copied or not is not really matter? Is there any policy/meta post for the "perfectly acceptable partly-answered answers"?

Comment: You mean, when it's "not matching the policy" anyway, why not add to that? :confused: Remember those posts were deleted because they were duplicates. // Apart from that, I'd prefer to stay out of this discussion for a little and see other members' opinions first :)

Comment: Can someone post a screenshot of the answer?

Comment: @unor: Added screenshot of deleted answer.